# Cambridge English Certification

Tags: usage, expressions

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post a question like the following (and if not, I'd be happy to be redirected to a better one, maybe still on StackExchange), but since I have no other ideas, I'll ask anyway:

I've recently taken the CAE (Cambridge English Advanced, or C1 level) exam, being awarded grade A with an overall score of 205 on the Cambridge English Scale, which corresponds to CEFR C2 level.

My question is: can I write on my CV that I achieved C2 level or not?

---

INFO: The front page of my certificate states:

> Cambridge English Level 3 Certificate in ESOL International (Advanced)*
>
> This is to certify that *NAME SURNAME* has been awarded **Grade A** in the **Certificate in Advanced English**
>
> Performance at Grade A demonstrates an
>   ability at Level 3* and Council of Europe Level C2
>
> **Overall Score 205**
>
> [...]
>
> *This level refers to the UK National Qualifications Framework

On the back:

> Results are reported using scores on the Cambridge English Scale and
>   certificates are awarded to candidates who achieve the following
>   grades:
>
> Grade A - CEFR Level C2 (score 200-210)
>
> Grade B - CEFR Level C1 (score
>   193-199)
>
> Grade C - CEFR Level C1 (score 180-192)
>
> Candidates who have achieved a score between 200 and 210 (Grade A)
>   have demonstrated ability at CEFR Level C2. Candidates who have not
>   achieved a passing grade, but score between 160 and 179, receive a
>   certificate stating they demonstrated ability at CEFR Level B2.

Asking to a couple of friends and to the manager of the English school where I took the test I got opposing views on the subject. Can you enlighten me?

For the time being my choice is to state this on my CV:

```
Certified C2 level, Cambridge English C1 Advanced qualification (Dec. 2018)
Cambridge English Scale score: 205
```

Comment: You may have to produce the certificate, and it does not certify C2 level. It says your ability is *equivalent to C2*, so you should put what the certifcate says, and not be interpretive.

Comment: @WeatherVane how would you state it, providing both the information of the test taken (C1) and the equivalence of the achieved score to C2?

Comment: Writing CVs is off topic, but you must never put anything in a CV that you can be called out on. You achieved Grade A in the Certificate in Advanced English, equivalent to CEFR level C2.